# Responsive design with changes in CSS as opposed to HTML

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

The scenario is that we are using a CMS third party product that hosts about 5-6 sites, and a lot of shared components are used throughout the sites.

Given our specific implementation and customization of the product, it's feasible to apply/load specific CSS for a given site, but it's harder to make changes to the HTML/components, since they are re-used on many of the sites.

Our team is looking to implement responsive design on just one of the websites, not all of them, so, without taking into consideration implementation details and just as a feasibility question, would it be possible to fully implement responsive web design using CSS only, and not using a mobile-first or responsive framework, which would require modifying the HTML to accommodate their responsive classes?

I'm not an expert in web design, but from what I've seen so far is that in responsive design, the bulk of the implementation is with CSS Media queries, but can it be done 100%, and not rely on JS for any of the responsive design features?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is YES, I would say. Few years back, there wasn't a such thing called "responsive design" or the concept of "mobile first", lots of the companies wanted to update their sites to be mobile friendly, they also wanted to keep the costs down, which basically means - tweaking the current site rather than a redesign and rebuild. So the easiest way would be keeping everything untouched, but adding a mobile stylesheet. That method works for quite a while I believe.

There are limits by only doing with CSS, you'll have to make the clients to understand it. Basically saying "The site may not look perfect on the mobile devices, but it will be much more accessible and usable." And for developers and designers we'll have to convince our selves to accept what we have and what we did is good enough while working on the code. Of course, the more time spending to better it looks. But it can be endless if you're pushing to much.

One tip here - working on this kind of CSS, don't be afraid of using `!important` rules, such as to rest everything to `width: auto !important`, `float: none !important` etc. That will make things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Of course. How hard is it? If you already have a ton of css, it will probably be painful.... You may just want to consider starting your css from scratch. Using something like sass might make it less terrible. Really all comes down to the requirements, your team's front end experience and deadline.

Comment: So there are absolutely no responsive design features that can only be achieved through HTML/JS? I guess my question could've been worded better: are there any responsive design features that can only be implemented through HTML or JS and not CSS?

Comment: None that i can think of at the moment

Comment: so just for reference, how extensive is your experience implementing responsive web design?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot to work with only using CSS.

Of course, the options and approach will vary site to site depending on design and the base code.

You can add JavaScript for smooth effects ( e.g. Masonry ) but most responsive sites whether mobile or desktop first are based on targeted media queries as you mentioned you have experience with.

As previous commenters noted, you may need to override styles with !important declarations if you're not able to add classes within your HTML where necessary for your style customizations.

Or.. make all the sites responsive! It's 2015 :)